# Envelope detector circuits explanation

Tags: circuit-analysis

Why do these 2 circuits produce differen output signals (something has to do with charging/discharging capacitor)? Please explain in detail and how does the envelope detector work based on this[image][image]

Comment: Why is it an LVDT?

Comment: I posted the question with the circuit attached now

Comment: @Flaiber - Hi, "*I posted the question with the circuit attached now*" Bad plan :-( That breaks the rules here. Now we'll have to close one of your questions as a duplicate of the other, causing some work where it wasn't needed until you duplicated your posting :-( In future, you **edit** the original posting in a situation like this; you don't post the same question again. Since it looks like this one has already got some close votes, then this is the one that's getting closed. Please go and fix the *original* question - edit that one and add the missing schematic there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The first system is running 1000 times faster than the second. This means that in the first system the charging time constant becomes significant (100 ohm/100 n = 10 us = 1 cycle) and it takes several cycles for the cap to charge. Not much time for the cap to discharge between cycles compared to discharge time constant (100 n/100 k = 10 ms). In the second system the cap is charged on the first cycle, to all intents and purposes, but discharges between cycles. By the way, diode is reversed compared to schematic.

Comment: Can you explain how does the envelope detector work, based on this ?

Comment: An envelope detector usually has a short charging time constant to charge up to the RF peaks and a longer discharge time constant that allows the output to approximately follow the envelope of the signal without discharging much between cycles.